# Community Promotion Ads

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

<strike>We'll be entering public beta soon,</strike> We're in public beta, so we need to get word out to the rest of Stack Exchange about Law Stack Exchange. One of the best ways of doing this is with Community Promotion Ads.

Here is part of the canonical spiel given on meta posts on graduated sites where we submit our ads for voting (six upvotes and our ad is shown on the site), repurposed for a different use:

> #### What are Community Promotion Ads?
>
> Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will
>   show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this
>   question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are
>   provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be
>   shown.
>
> #### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?
>
> This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to
>   visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following
>   things:
>
> - the site's twitter account
> - useful tools or resources for physics research
> - interesting articles or findings for the curious
> - cool events or conferences
> - anything else your community would genuinely be interested in
>
> The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your
>   community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote
>   information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's
>   interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to
>   join.
>
> #### Why do we reset the ads every year?
>
> Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other
>   things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads
>   every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served
>   their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This
>   helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject
>   matter of the community, but to the current status of the community.
>   We reset the ads once a year, every December.
>
> The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an
>   ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very
>   valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good
>   idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the
>   process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale
>   after a year of exposure.
>
> #### Image requirements
>
> - The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
> - Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
> - Must be GIF or PNG
> - No animated GIFs
> - Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

For more information, see [What's the best way to create a community ad for a beta site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247037/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-community-ad-for-a-beta-site).

I invite everyone to submit ideas for our ad as answers, following the above guidelines.

Comment: This is, by the way, pretty much identical to [its counterpart on Law](http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/157/community-promotion-ads).

Comment: Whoops, I meant "Mythology."

Comment: As far as the image goes I favour something jurisdiction-neutral like the scales of justice (no gavels please!)... but I'm no designer so that's as much as I can contribute :)

Comment: Wait, isn't this topic supposed to be used for promoting OTHER communities at law.se?

Comment: @cnst No, not in this format. Most beta sites use a thread like this to come up with ideas.

Answer (score 5):

For [Movies & TV SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1745/community-promotion-ads-2015):

[image: Suits]

> #### Submitted at [Movies SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1873/940) Go vote for it!

[image: Join Law.SE]

It might need a better hook, though? Something about questioning whether what you see on TV/movies is real, but more succinct.

Also I now sort of feel like these might be barking up the wrong tree, because of https://law.stackexchange.com/q/1035/58

---

[Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/):

> #### Submitted at [Travel SE](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3330/3328). Go vote for it!

[image: Travel.SE]:

---

[Workplace.SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/):

I realise the colours are bad, but there's too much range in that photo :P

I'll upload another version shortly.

[image: Workplace]

I was also thinking of doing something from *The Office* to pull people from Workplace.SE. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

#### This ad was posted to Photography SE - Vote for it and help get the word out!

Vote for it there: https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4809/41598

[image: Find and ask more questions like this on Law Stack Exchange!]

Answer (score 2):

#### Here's one I've sent to Sci-fi & Fantasy. [Vote for it there!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7090/24082)

[image: Join Law SE. Ask awesome questions.]

Comment: I'm not sure that SF&F is a good spot for it.

Comment: @HDE226868 - Certainly our most important need is for [legal experts](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/q/79/10).  But we also need participants, and  it seems like for that purpose publicity in _any_ venue (with the exception of [freeman advocacy groups](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/q/22/10)) would likely be beneficial.  If you think not please explain!

Comment: @feetwet See [Robert's comment here](http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/157/community-promotion-ads#comment288_157). See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147312/appropriate-content-for-community-ads.

Comment: RIchard (mod on SF & F) says it's okay. cc @feetwet.

Comment: @HDE226868 it's just that law is about _everything_, right? :P But no, I'm not just picking things at random... If things we're asking are relevant to other sites, that's where I'm focusing.

Comment: @jimsug Eh, I upvoted the one on SF & F, and this one.

Answer (score 2):

#### This is on Academia.  [Vote for it there!](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1907/37048)

[image: Participate on Law Stack Exchange!]

Answer (score 0):

https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2096/16831
https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/636/8438

[image: Do you have the right to keep and bear crypto?]